# Is the usage of "wocao" in this context unprecedented?

Tags: apt

In this whitepaper, they use a HTTP server history (see screenshot) as the basis for the codename of an identified attack, "Operation Wocao".

[image: web shell]

https://www.fox-it.com/en/news/whitepapers/operation-wocao-shining-a-light-on-one-of-chinas-hidden-hacking-groups/

The attackers (presumably APT20) were shown to be extremely competent technically.  I was curious whether the use of a word like "wocao" is a reliable indicator of nationality.

In other articles, I have often seen nation-state actors leave misleading cultural/linguistic fingerprints in more obscure places than a webshell (code metadata, registrar email's backup email etc.), but presumably not in realtime.

In particular, I would like to know if (correctly) culturally-identifying phrases are known to have been obtained from realtime interaction by a nation-state attacker.

- Since such instances are likely to be guarded information, I refer only to publicly available information (e.g. white papers, incident reports, journalism)

Comment: There is no possible way that we could come up with an answer to that. We'd all be guessing.

Comment: The edit doesn't really help. You essentially ask if correct culturally-identifying phrases have *ever* been discovered in attacks. Uh, yes, they have. How is this useful to you? If you are asking for references for such instances, that's off-topic (the list could go on forever). Instead, why do you want to know?

Comment: I could personally show you quite a lot of honeypot logs where the attacker very clearly discloses culturally-identifying information. So, the question becomes, what will knowing this do for you?

Comment: Sorry, I'm mostly offline this week and haven't been able to give your responses the attention they deserve.  I'll take another stab at it "next year" to see if there is anything meaningful to ask.